# HoverMenuExtender not working

Tags: asp.net, ajax

Here's my code, I followed a tutorial but cannot figure out why it doesn' work

```
        <form id="form1" runat = "server">
            <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
            <div>
            <asp:HoverMenuExtender ID="HoverMenuExtender1" 
                        runat="server"
                        TargetControlID = "OR"
                        PopupControlID = "PanelOR"
                        PopupPosition = "bottom"
                        OffsetX = "6"
                        PopDelay = "50"
                        HoverCssClass = "popupHover">
            </asp:HoverMenuExtender>

            <asp:Panel ID="PanelOR" 
                        runat="server" 
                        Height = "50px"
                        Width="200px" 
                        CssClass="popupMenu">
                   <asp:LinkButton ID="Attribution" runat="server" CommandName="One" Text="Attribution"></asp:LinkButton><br />
                   <asp:LinkButton ID="Gestion" runat="server" Text="Gestion des OR"></asp:LinkButton>
            </asp:Panel>              
               <asp:LinkButton ID="OR" runat="server">should happen here</asp:LinkButton>
            </div>
            </form>
```

On the css file

```
.popupMenu 
{
    visibility:hidden;
}

.popupHover 
{
    background-color:White;
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It doesn't show the hover menu when you hover over the libkButton with id "OR" ?

Comment: @Deeptechtons exactely. The only thing that happens on hover is that it's background color changes to white. But no sign of the panel. I tested it on many browsers. I must be missing something

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently I cannot use the toolkit with MVC 2

Answer (score 0):

You must make the panel to be displayed as none to be hovered

```
.popupMenu 
{
display:none;
}
```

Update:
I don't know why it doesn't work but here is the quick code i wrote and it just works out of the box.

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:Panel ID="Panel1" runat="server" CssClass="pnl">
            <input type="button" value="button1" id="btn1" />
            <input type="button" value="button2" id="btn2" />
        </asp:Panel>
        <asp:HoverMenuExtender ID="HoverMenuExtender1" runat="server" BehaviorID="hmeBehaviour"
            PopupPosition="Bottom" TargetControlID="LinkButton1" PopupControlID="Panel1">
        </asp:HoverMenuExtender>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>

.pnl
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#CFCFCF;
    border:1px solid #CECECE;
    color:#CF0000;
}
```

when i hover over link button i get the two buttons below the link button.

Comment: no, it didn't. It seems the Ajax Toolkit doesn't work with MVC (yeah I fortgot to mention I was using MVC)

Comment: @Lucas dooh. you are Free to use jQuery and jQuery UI. Expecting a top notch UI experience then try Ext Js